# Prevention vs. Avoidance

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between prevention and avoidance?

Can you give generic examples?
The reason for my question is, that I want to know the difference between preventing and avoiding a threat against a (technical) system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent something means to stop it from happening.

To avoid something means to make sure that it doesn't affect you.

Thus we can avoid the rain, but not prevent it, for example.

However, one strategy for avoiding something is to prevent it.  Thus we could say that we avoided a crisis by preventing it from happening in the first place.

In the case of a technical threat, where the cause of the threat is some hacker in a room somewhere, you can't really prevent it, unless you go and arrest him.  But you could **avoid** it with extra security.

Some other types of threat may be able to be prevented completely.